# Converter String em Array - Java/Groovy

Tags: java, array, groovy

Preciso converter uma variável `string` em um `array`, tentei fazer da seguinte forma, possuo a variável `string` **conteudoLote**, onde seu valor é:

```
[["4","SCAB171301BF5","Vazio","Lexmark International","50F0Z00",null,null,"2017-10-27 08:54:56",false,"ROMUALDO SANTOS"]]
```

Tentei converter a mesma para array da seguinte forma:

```
def array = conteudoLote.toCharArray()
for (List listaTeste : array){
    logger.info("NÚMERO DE SÉRIE: "+listaTeste.get(1).toString()) //Aqui serve somente para visualizar o conteúdo do index 1 do meu array
}
```

Porém ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot cast object '[' with class 'java.lang.Character' to class 'java.util.List'
```

Como posso converter essa `string` para `array` então? Minha necessidade é conseguir pegar essa parte da string `SCAB171301BF5` que seria o index 1 no caso.

Comment: Você já transformou a String em um array de char. No seu `for` você deve trocar `List` por `char`.

Comment: @LeonardoLima, como posso acessa o conteúdo desse meu `array` assim? Pois preciso por exemplo pegar isso da minha string `SCAB171301BF5` que seria o index 1 do meu array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua variavel é uma string e que é um array:

```
def arrayString = '''[["4","SCAB171301BF5","Vazio","Lexmark International","50F0Z00",null,null,"2017-10-27 08:54:56",false,"ROMUALDO SANTOS"]]'''
```

Você pode dar um `Eval.me()`

```
def lista = Eval.me(arrayString)

lista[0].each{
    println it
}​
```

[Pode testar aqui, no groovy console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5166012299214848)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isto que tu queria fazer, mas dá uma olhada no código que gerei a partir da tua pergunta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //teu vetor tem valores null e false (boolean) que não podem estar no vetor
    String[] vetor= {"4","SCAB171301BF5","Vazio","Lexmark International","50F0Z00","2017-10-27 08:54:56","ROMUALDO SANTOS"};

    for (String palavra : vetor) {
        char []letras = palavra.toCharArray();

        for (char letra : letras) {
            System.out.println(letra);
        }
    }
}
```